# How can I append lists to an R data frame?

Tags: r, ggmap

I've been playing around with the [ggmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html) R package and I really like it's plotting features for showing geographic data. I've been trying to make simple plots of some city population data I have with the `geocode` function, but I can't figure out how to arrange the data in a logical fashion. As it stands, I've got data structured in a list like so

```
              City  Type Population
1          Detroit  city     713777
2     Grand Rapids  city     188040
3           Warren  city     134056
4 Sterling Heights  city     129699
5          Lansing  city     114297
6        Ann Arbor  city     113934
```

and I'd like to append "columns" with the latitude and longitude entries returned by `geocode`. Specifically, if the above dataframe is named Michigan, I'm grabbing coordinates with

```
lapply(as.vector(michigan$City), geocode)
```

which takes a string (in this case, a city name) and uses the Google Maps api to guess at coordinates, producing a list of lists:

```
[[1]]
        lon      lat
1 -83.04575 42.33143

[[2]]
        lon      lat
1 -85.66809 42.96336

[[3]]
       lon    lat
1 -83.0282 42.493

[[4]]
       lon      lat
1 -83.0302 42.58031

[[5]]
        lon      lat
1 -84.55553 42.73253

[[6]]
        lon      lat
1 -83.74304 42.28083
```

I'd like to append the latitude and longitude values to the `michigan` data frame as "columns", but because the result of my `lapply` is a list of lists, this is trickier than just slicing some arrays -- what's the best way to do this idiomatically in R?

Comment: Can you post some example code and data that you're using for the `geocode()` function? The short answer is probably using the `merge()` function, unless your data is really well structured in which case `cbind()` may  be sufficient.

Comment: Try `ldply` from **plyr** instead of `lapply` or `do.call(rbind,...)` on the result.

Comment: Hey. Where's Traverse City?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
cbind(your_df, geocode(your_df$City))
```